# OpenSource .net SMS library, I can't seem to find one at all for C#

Tags: c#, .net, sms, serial-port, gsm

I've been using GSM modems in my projects to **send/recieve** SMS-s. I have been using built-in serial port communication features of **.net** to do this by using standard AT commands.

Now I have to extend its functionality (like SMSs in PDU mode, more efficient delivery report handling etc). I don't wanna reinvent the wheel, so first I'd like to know if there is a good open source project or a free library on this topic. It should send/recieve sms in text and pdu mode, handle delivery reports.

I've googled it, but I have not found an efficient one so far.

Platform:
**Windows/.net4/vs2010/c#**

Comment: @ Tom :How are you exactly going to send SMS with your extend functionality? Are you going to get rid of the GSM modem and going to use a SMS gateway?

Comment: I have to use GSM modem because of my clients. They have it and they use it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted your GSM modem developer for API / SDK ?

Comment: My partners has various type of GSM modems, so I need a general, AT command based solution.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 4):

Since, you are not looking for just a client library, you need to deploy your own SMS gateway. [This is](http://www.kannel.org/) what you need

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any experiences about using it in .net?

Comment: No, I do not have experience with it using it in .net.

Comment: I just asked because as I see it does not have a .net wrapper, so I can not use it in my project

Comment: As you can read [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/256831-sending-sms-through-c) Kannel is using HTTP and a guy has built a C# client and does the work fine. Also, there is definitely a java api and this guy [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/preparing-c-net-api-kannel.html) has started porting this to C#. You can ask him more info. Maybe you can find useful this one [too](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/6138-send-sms-using-c.aspx). Nevertheless, a lot of people have done the job in the past, using C# to connect o Kannel and it works pretty with charm.

Comment: Thanks. And the Kannel itself runs only on Linux or can be run on Windows?

Comment: It runs on Linux, which I recommend - Pretty standard stuff with absolute reliability, no surprises, does the job like a perfect worker. You can rely upon.

Comment: Thanks, bad news for me, my partners won't use Linux just for this purpose.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3893/discussion-between-panayotis-matsinopoulos-and-tom)

Answer (score 3):

I accually wrote my own SMS library in C#, back in 2005. My aim was to create a commercial library out of it, but it just never happened; besides this is probably my 1000 th project that has never been released... Anyway I decided to change that - because of this question - and will now start to release much of my superfine code under MIT license (free, free, free).

https://github.com/johanssonrobotics/FJR.SmsSolution (click the link, then the "Zip" button on GitHub to download)

Anyway, as I said, I wrote most of the code in 2005, but did some heavy refactoring to it about a year ago, so it should be solid. Anyway, feel free to test it. Comes with a demo Windows-forms application.

[image]

For instance, this could be used to connect a phone via COM-cable and send/receive SMS-messages. Easily.

Have fun & hope this helps!

Comment: Did you test the library? How did it work?

Comment: I looked its code, it is nice by implementation, but it is lack of a lot of features I need. Thanks for your effort anyway, very nice from you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use a local phone/gsm modem via serial you can use the following.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx?msg=2961173
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/smspdulib.aspx

Local serial sending will be quite slow and not good for high volume sending of messages. If you need to send high volume of sms you will need to use some sort of sms gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the APIs provided by [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/)?  I haven't used it but I gathered that if you use your own gateway, it's free, and if use theirs, it's reasonably priced.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/index.htm) just now:

Does anybody has experiences wit it?

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

You should be able to use the .NET CE Framework (from within Windows) to accomplish this.

[Sending SMSs from your Microsoft .NET Compact Framework-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446545.aspx)

.NET Compact Framework has built-in handling for sending SMS-s and PDU over a GSM operator and it's fairly well documented.

Also, while not straight .NET, you have options available in the base mobile/broadband api's, it's straight Windows, and can be wrapped/imported using standard .NET technologies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323268%28v=VS.85%29.aspx